# change button image onClick android

Tags: android, button

I have a button and two images, i want the default image for the button to be **btn1.jpg** and when the button is clicked, the image should immediately change to **btn2.jpg** and after **3 seconds**, it should again revert back to **btn1.jpg**. please tell me how do i achieve this?

```
    package com.example.btn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View ButtonName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void yolo(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonName:
                ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn2);
                //Disable click on Button
               ButtonName.setEnabled(false);
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(3000);
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
               ButtonName.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn1));
               break;

            case default:
                ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change the button background image in the OnClick method to **btn2.jpg**. After that, you must start a timer to count down 3 seconds and, after that, change again the button image to **btn1.jpg**

```
private final int interval = 3000;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn2))

        //Start runnable after 3 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);

    }
});

runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
       btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn1)) 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**finally figured it out myself!**

1. Set background for button in xml
2. use this code:

   ```
   package com.example.btn;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Handler;
   import android.view.View;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       Handler mHandler; // global instance
       Runnable your_runnable; // global instance

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }

       public void yolo(final View view) {

           if (view == view) {
               view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);
               mHandler = new Handler();
               your_runnable = new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn2);

                  }

               };

               mHandler.postDelayed(your_runnable, 3000L);// 3sec timer

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first, you have a mistake here :

```
ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(getresources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn2));
```

And after, add a clickListener on your button :

```
private Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(getresources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn2));
       //Disable click on Button
       ButtonName.setEnabled(false);
       try {
           Thread.sleep(3000);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
          e.printstacktrace();
       }
       ButtonName.setBackgroundResource(getresources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn1));
    }
 });

 ButtonName.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener (
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       t.start();
    }
 ));
```

I think it is what you want

Comment: Without onClickListener, i don't know how you can detect click on a Button. It is much easier to use a Button and a ClickListener

Comment: this Thread.sleep is not the best for that. Your are blocking the UI thread and the onClick event. You must leave the onClick event to finish, and then start whatever you want to make the other action.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button button;
  private Handler handler;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);

          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

             button.setBackgroundResource(getresources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn1));
             handler=new Handler();
             handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                     button.setBackgroundResource(getresources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn2));
            }
        }, 3000);


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it should have, but it's not error free. please edit the code in question and post it instead. thanks